# Vampires in Religious texts

Tags: mythical-creatures, vampires

You know how the Torah says that there were Vampires who were called blood sucking demons. Are Vampires mention in other religious books or texts?

Comment: Try **Theresa Bane**'s (2013) "**Encyclopedia of Vampire Mythology**", it is well-researched and you should find all the answers you need.

Answer (score 2):

The Greeks had a myth on vampires found in Delphi scriptures.

> [That evening he walked to the pond and found a swan which he then killed and offered to Artemis who then appeared to him. She had been pleased with his loyalty and service to her and decided to to make him one last deal. Ambrogio could touch Selene just once-to drink her blood. This act would kill Selene’s mortal body but would guarantee that they would stay together forever.](https://authorlyngibson.wordpress.com/2014/09/24/ambrogio-a-greek-vampire-origination-thery/)
>
> [The Delphi scriptures offer a solid validation of ancient beliefs and evidence.](https://authorlyngibson.wordpress.com/2014/09/24/ambrogio-a-greek-vampire-origination-thery/)

The Babylonians had a vampire as well, which is adopted by Hebrew demonology.

> [Ancient Babylonia had tales of the mythical Lilitu, synonymous with and giving rise to Lilith (Hebrew לילית) and her daughters the Lilu from Hebrew demonology. Lilith was considered a demon and was often depicted as subsisting on the blood of babies. The legend of Lilith was originally included in some traditional Jewish texts: according to the medieval folk traditions, she was considered to be Adam's first wife before Eve.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vampire_folklore_by_region)
>
> [Scholars are not certain where the character of Lilith comes from, though many believe she was inspired by Sumerian myths about female vampires called “Lillu” or Mesopotamian myths about succubae (female night demons) called “lilin.” Lilith is mentioned four times in the Babylonian Talmud, but it is not until the Alphabet of Ben Sira (c. 800s to 900s) that the character of Lilith is associated with the first version of Creation.](https://www.thoughtco.com/legend-of-lilith-origins-2076660)

Comment: Well vampires are considered demons, a blood sucking demon. So are you just saying that she was a demon and not a vampire demon?

Comment: If it is immortal and is a blood sucker, you can call it any name you want... but for me it falls under the general concept of vampire.

Comment: Your definition of vampire comes into saying they are not demons. Then what species would they be classified as? Vampires have been around for a long time and re regarded as being demons. They are not a made up story how the media tries to make them out to be. For an example when involving Vampire magick it is usually involving a ritual to Lucifer.